# How to introduce a new if-condition for a specified case without any business logic given to implement that case?

Tags: java, oop, if-statement

Essentially, the task is to introduce a new status with id 10 (dtl.getOpStatId() is 10) in the code down below. I've been asked  to make any necessary changes to this code to add the required functionality( to add the additional operation stat id). Is there something obvious I'm missing????

I was given the following hint:
**if the only thing you are doing is adding dtl.getOpStatId() == 10 to the code below, you are not doing it correctly.**

```
public class ChangeMe {

public void doOp(Operation op, Map<Long, String> reliefOperationMap, OperationSummary sum) {
    for (int d = 0; d < op.getOperationDetails().size(); ) {
        OperationDetail dtl = op.getOperationDetails().get(d);
        if (dtl.getOpStatId() == 1 || dtl.getOpStatId() == 3 || dtl.getOpStatId() == 4) {
            sum.setOpCond(true);
            if (dtl.getRelblkId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumRefId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumParentId() != null) {
                sum.setIsReliefOperation("Y");
                reliefOperationMap.put(dtl.getOperationsumId(), "Y");
            }
        } else {
            if (dtl.getRelblkId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumRefId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumParentId() != null) {
                sum.setOpCond(true);
                sum.setIsReliefOperation("Y");
                reliefOperationMap.put(dtl.getOperationsumId(), "Y");
            } else {
                sum.setOpCond(true);
            }
        }
        break;
      }
   }
}
```

This what I have so far. I can't think of anything else **considering there are no implementations given for the objects that are being passed to this method** (doOp()).

```
public static void doOp(Operation op, Map<Long, String> reliefOperationMap, OperationSummary sum) {

/*Missing increment condition from for loop, will be endlessly looping on 
the first element of the ArrayList (op.getOperationDetails())*/

    for (int d = 0; d < op.getOperationDetails().size(); d++ ) {
        OperationDetail dtl = op.getOperationDetails().get(d);
        if (dtl.getOpStatId() == 1 || dtl.getOpStatId() == 3 || dtl.getOpStatId() == 4) {
            sum.setOpCond(true);
            if (dtl.getRelblkId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumRefId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumParentId() != null) {
                sum.setIsReliefOperation("Y");
                reliefOperationMap.put(dtl.getOperationsumId(), "Y");
                System.out.println("Reached 1 or 3 or 4");
            }
        }else if(dtl.getOpStatId() == 10){

            //business logic for OpStatId here

        }else {
            System.out.println("Reached anything but 1,3 or 4");
            if (dtl.getRelblkId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumRefId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumParentId() != null) {
                sum.setOpCond(true);
                sum.setIsReliefOperation("Y");
                reliefOperationMap.put(dtl.getOperationsumId(), "Y");
            } else {
                sum.setOpCond(true);
            }
        }
/*removed break from here, no point of having a for loop if you're only 
 ever checking the first element of the Arraylist*/
    }
}
}
```

To Recap my changes : 
*Added a 'd++' in the for loop, otherwise it would be looping forever on the first element of the List.

*Added an else-if(dtl.getOpStatId() == 10) condition with empty business logic...I know they said this is wrong but I can't think of anything else

*removed break condition otherwise would only check the first element of the loop and exit the for loop

Comment: If this is an interview question, I would think that they want you to demonstrate the ability to have a good OO design. In this particular case, `op` and `dtl` are queried quite often and the return values used for performing other actions. All those queries should be encapsulated inside the `Operation` and `OperationDetail` classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to fix / clean up the code?

First, as you already saw, the `break` has to go, otherwise the loop won't ever loop.
So remove it.

But, if you remove it, the loop will run forever, since `d` is never incremented.
So add `d++`, or it'll loop forever.

```
for (int d = 0; d < op.getOperationDetails().size(); d++) {
    OperationDetail dtl = op.getOperationDetails().get(d);
    if (dtl.getOpStatId() == 1 || dtl.getOpStatId() == 3 || dtl.getOpStatId() == 4) {
        sum.setOpCond(true);
        if (dtl.getRelblkId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumRefId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumParentId() != null) {
            sum.setIsReliefOperation("Y");
            reliefOperationMap.put(dtl.getOperationsumId(), "Y");
        }
    } else {
        if (dtl.getRelblkId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumRefId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumParentId() != null) {
            sum.setOpCond(true);
            sum.setIsReliefOperation("Y");
            reliefOperationMap.put(dtl.getOperationsumId(), "Y");
        } else {
            sum.setOpCond(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Now ask yourself, when is `sum.setOpCond(true);` *not* called?
It is always called, so move it outside the `if` statements.

```
for (int d = 0; d < op.getOperationDetails().size(); d++) {
    OperationDetail dtl = op.getOperationDetails().get(d);
    sum.setOpCond(true);
    if (dtl.getOpStatId() == 1 || dtl.getOpStatId() == 3 || dtl.getOpStatId() == 4) {
        if (dtl.getRelblkId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumRefId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumParentId() != null) {
            sum.setIsReliefOperation("Y");
            reliefOperationMap.put(dtl.getOperationsumId(), "Y");
        }
    } else {
        if (dtl.getRelblkId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumRefId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumParentId() != null) {
            sum.setIsReliefOperation("Y");
            reliefOperationMap.put(dtl.getOperationsumId(), "Y");
        }
    }
}
```

Now ask yourself, what is the difference between the `if` block and the `else` block?
None, so eliminate the outer `if` statement.

```
for (int d = 0; d < op.getOperationDetails().size(); d++) {
    OperationDetail dtl = op.getOperationDetails().get(d);
    sum.setOpCond(true);
    if (dtl.getRelblkId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumRefId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumParentId() != null) {
        sum.setIsReliefOperation("Y");
        reliefOperationMap.put(dtl.getOperationsumId(), "Y");
    }
}
```

Now, change the loop to an enhanced `for` loop.

```
for (OperationDetail dtl : op.getOperationDetails()) {
    sum.setOpCond(true);
    if (dtl.getRelblkId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumRefId() != null && dtl.getOperationsumParentId() != null) {
        sum.setIsReliefOperation("Y");
        reliefOperationMap.put(dtl.getOperationsumId(), "Y");
    }
}
```

And finally, *"introduce a new status with id 10 (`dtl.getOpStatId()` is 10)"*.
Well, since `getOpStatId()` isn't used anywhere, any more, the code will support any new status without modification, so there is nothing to do.

Now that you've realized this, you can actually go back to the original assignment. Were you actually asked to "fix" the code, or just support status 10? Remember, according to what you wrote:

> the task is to introduce a new status with id 10 (dtl.getOpStatId() is 10) in the code down below. I've been asked to **make any *necessary* changes** to this code to add the required functionality

So the real answer is: **No code change necessary!**

Comment: This is perfect and really helps me to keep an eye for these simple optimizations moving forward. Thank you so much! I hope one day I can solve these problem with the ease you've done it with!